# Gentoo Barebones X installation for window forwarding

Tags: ssh, gentoo, x

I have a gentoo installation which does not have X installed. This gentoo is a ssh entry point from the internet and allows me to ssh into other machines on the LAN. I want X window forwarding from these LAN machines but it appears that I need to install the X Server on the Gentoo machine to allow for the X Window Forwarding. I understand the X is massive and seeing that my gentoo is running on old hardware, I was wondering if there was a subset of X that I could install to simply enable X forwarding in ssh hoping. I think last time I compiled X on this machine took over a day (maybe even two) and I am trying to avoid this.

To clarify, I am using the gentoo machine as a jump server.

I'm using the net-misc/openssh client at the moment. I've looked at the USE flags and X is not one of them.

Comment: Gentoo has minimal dependencies, just install the apps you wish to forward, and a minimal X environment should be pulled as a dependency. If you have a problem we need more details, how did you connect, how is ssh configured, and what error did you get. If you are forwarding a browser, use port forwarding

Comment: See also https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-936362-start-0.html

Comment: The X server usually runs on the computer that you're sitting in front of. Are you physically interacting with this Gentoo system, or is it some kind of jump host that you're accessing remotely?

Comment: It's a jump host I'm remotely accessing. X Forwarding to the machine gives me a `X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0`.